# Junit mockito when(..).thenReturn() NullPointerException

Tags: spring, junit, mocking

I am writing the unit test to Class_b and getting Null pointers exception due to when().thenReturn(). Found it through the debugger. Any help will be appreciable.

```
@Component
Class_b{
    
    @Autowired
    private Class_a class_a;

    fun_b(par){
        result = class_a.fun_a()
        // uses result and returns
    }
}

@Component
Class_a{
    
    fun_a(par){
        // Some logic
        returns;
    }
}

@Runner
Class_b_Test{

   @InjectMocks
   private Class_b class_b;

   @Mock
   private Class_a class_a;

   @Test
   fun_testing(){
        when(class_a.fun_a(par)).thenReturn(something)
        result = class_b.fun_b(par)
         // Does validation
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing Spring boot application?

If you are testing Spring boot application you should add 3 annotations to the test class (example for JUnit 5):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

They will initialize Spring context with your beans.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class Class_b_Test {

    @InjectMocks
    private Class_b class_b;

    @Mock
    private Class_a class_a;

    @Test
    void fun_b() {

        when(class_a.fun_a()).thenReturn("");
        class_b.fun_b();
    }
}
```

==============================================

Update according to the comment:

When I added `Class_a.class` to the `@SpringBootTest` like that

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Class_b.class,Class_a.class})
```

this test has bean passed.

I'm testing with this dependencies

```
<properties>
    <powermock.version>2.0.2</powermock.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>    
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Yes, It is a spring boot application and I am using Junit4

These are the annotations I am using
@SpringBootTest(classes = Class_b.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Class_b.class)

Comment: @PawanAsipu please send me your GitHub account and I share with you repo with full example

Comment: @PawanAsipu is this your account Asipu Pawan Kumar? I have invited you to the private repo on GitHub with full example